# Next Button Should Switch Between 3 Images

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image that displays on my webpage and a "Next Image" button. When the button is clicked, I want it to change the image that is displayed by calling a javascript function. I thought I had this thing figured out and was all excited until I tried it and it didn't work. Now I can't figure out WHY it doesn't work.

This is the function that gets called by the Next Image button:

```
function showNext()
            {
                if (document.getElementById("Apples").style.display=="inline")
                {
                    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="inline";
                    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display=="inline")
                {
                    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="inline";
                }
                else (document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display=="inline")
                {
                    document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="inline";
                    document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
                    document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
                }
            }
```

This is the HTML for my images:

```
<img id="Apples" src="/fruit/apples.jpg" height="267" width="400" alt="apples" />
        <img id="Grapes" src="/fruit/grapes.jpg" height="267" width="400" alt="grapes" />
        <img id="Strawberry" src="/fruit/strawberries.jpg" height="267" width="400" alt="grapes" />
```

This is my html for my Button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next Image" onClick="showNext();" />
```

Comment: Your HTML matters, please include it.

Comment: updated to include HTML for images and button

Comment: The right way to do this is advancing by index and not with a bunch of hard-coded selectors.

Comment: Well i understand that, but I couldn't get that to work either and one of the CS tutors at my school suggested I try it this way. Neither of us can figure out why this isn't working though. I'd rather get this to work first so that I have something if I can't figure it out the "right way"

Comment: Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj5Wk/) but it shows all the images on the first click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an if-statement, you should use == instead of =. One equals sign is for assigning a value ;)

```
function showNext()
{
    if (document.getElementById("Apples").style.display=="inline")
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display=="inline")
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="inline";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

For more information regarding comparisons, you can check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) out.

Overlooked the last else call, should work now.
You can't specify a condition in an else statement, use else if for that :).

Comment: I added the double equals just a moment ago and it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you don't have the `display` property defined off the start, so none of those if conditions are met. What if you change your javascript to this, so it will set the `display` property on the first one the first time through:

```
function showNext()
{
    if (document.getElementById("Apples").style.display=="inline")
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display=="inline")
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="inline";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("Apples").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("Grapes").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Strawberry").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Comment: display is defined in a .css file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming HTML like:

```
<div id="img_wrapper">
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

you'd use a loop like this:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("img_wrapper");
var images = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("img");
var imgCt = images.length - 1; // account for zero-based indexing
var i1 = 1;

function showNext() {
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < images.length; i2++) {
        images[i2].style.display = 'none';
    }

    images[i1].style.display = 'inline ';

    if (i1 < imgCt)
        i1++;
    } else {
        i1 = 0;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/FDf82